# Can someone help me understand why my bevel modifier messes up my mesh?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edges, bevel

I'm trying to model this hangboard here: It's the [Beastmaker 2000](https://soillholds.com/products/beastmaker-2000).

[image]

I'm doing this for some hard surface modeling practice (I'm not even 2.5 months into Blender). I scaled up and extruded the basic shape with a plane, and added some loop cuts to make sure I had loops that went all the way around the model.

[image]

I should note that I'm planning on doing all the holes with booleans (at least, I hope so... hoping that will go smoother than this, ha). Right now I'm trying to apply a bevel modifier so that I can get the nice smooth edges as seen in the reference.

However, when I try to apply one, the top edge gets messed up, presumably because of how I extruded the basic shape? Can someone take a look at point me in the right direction?

Before the Bevel modifier:
[image]

After the Bevel modifier:
[image]

As you can see, the topmost edge has that really deep crease in it? I don't know how to fix it. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: In the modifier remember to make a limit method is selected, preferably Angle. Otherwise it will bevel every single edge regardless of its location in the geometry.

Comment: Oh I've definitely done that.. I've played with all the options.. I think there's an issue with my topology or something, but I'm too inexperienced to figure it out.